# If sequences $A$ and $B$ satisfy $A,B=B,A$ then $A$ and $B$ are concatenations of the same sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

> If $A$ and $B$ are finite sequences and $A,B=B,A$ (where the comma denotes the concatenation of sequences), then both $A$ and $B$ are repetitions of some sequence $C$.

Let $A=\left(a_i\right)_{i=1}^m$ and $B=\left(b_i\right)_{i=1}^n$, then the condition $$A,B=B,A$$ is equivalent to $$a_1,\ldots, a_m, b_1,\ldots,b_n=b_1,\ldots, b_n, a_1,\ldots, a_m .$$

If $m=n$ then we obtain $A=B$, in which case we can just take $C=A$.

On the other hand, if $m<n$, then we obtain $b_i=a_i$ for $i\le m$ and $b_{m+k}=b_k$ for $1\le k \le n-m.$

At this point, we have some $b$'s which have two constraints (if $i\le \min(m, n-m)$ then $b_i=a_i=b_{n-i}$) and I am unsure of how to identify the sequence $C$.

Comment: Well $c_1 = a_1 = b_1$ and $c_2 = a_2 = b_2$, right? How can you find the next terms of $C$?

Comment: I would like to keep writing what you wrote until I reach the index $m$; giving $c_1,\ldots, c_m$. After that, the sequence should start repeating terms such as $c_{m+1}=c_1, \ldots. c_{m+n}=c_n$, but my issues with the latest equation that I do not want $C$ to have more than $m$ terms.

Comment: The sequence $C$ can have at most $\gcd(m,n)$ terms. Put differently its length must divide both $m$ and $n$.

Comment: There is a proof of this by induction on the lengths of the sequences. Can you reduce the problem down to a similar problem with smaller sequences?

Comment: @TomKern I considered the case $n-m<m$ and obtained that $B$ is a concatenation of $(b_1, \ldots, b_{n-m})$, but then I need to show that this sequence can potentially be shortened when writing the terms of $A$.

Comment: Suppose wlog that $|A| < |B|$. From the identity $A,B = B,A$ we can get two derived identities, one found by removing $A$ at the front and another from removing $B$ at the rear. From these, we can find $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A,B$ are strings of length $|A|,|B| \le 1$ and $AB=BA$ then there is some string $D$ such that $A=D^k,B=D^l$ with $k,l \in \{0,1,..\}$.

Suppose that when $A,B$ are strings of length $|A|,|B| \le n$ and $AB=BA$ then there is some string $D$ such that $A=D^k,B=D^l$ with $k,l \in \{0,1,..\}$.

Now suppose $|A| \le n+1, |B|=n+1$ and $AB=BA$. If $|A| = |B|$ then $A=B$ and we can take $D=A$, so suppose $|A| \le n$. Then we must have $B=AC$ for some $|C|\ge 1$. Then $AAC=ACA$ and so $AC=CA$ and hence there is some $D$ such that $A=D^k,C=D^l$. Then $A=D^k, B=D^{k+l}$.